# Where do Play! logs end up?

Tags: playframework

Sorry if this is a totally noobish question, but where do Play! logs go?  e.g. if I'm trying to find a full stack trace and Play! tells me something like `This exception has been logged with id 67hg12dhg`, where do I go to find that log?

Comment: That mesasge is only shown when running play in PROD mode. For developping, use `play run myapp` instead of `play start myapp`.

Comment: The fact that this isn't immediately obvious/searchable is completely crazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In DEV mode logs go to the console.

In PROD mode, logs are by default in logs/system.out

Check out [official documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/logs)

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  I'm looking for more information on a stack trace that ends with something like `... 14 more` to see if I can get more info on it.  Is there a way to increase the maximum amount of output from those?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You can try to take a look at the log4j configuration that is really powerfull and be configured very finely.

Comment: I see they go to logs/system.out in DEV mode as well, if you use `play start` instead of `play run` to start Play.

Comment: i can't find logs/system.out , and i have deployed application in glassfish

Comment: @Yusuf1494 i think that was the case for older versions of play, but it isnt for play 2.2.x. I just added a new answer matching the new versions of play

Comment: Thomas is right. This is not relevant to (2.2.x) or later versions of play.

Comment: my log messages don't go anywhere, not in the console, not in any file, i'm using Play 2.6, i'm wondering what's the use of this Logger class

Answer (score 5):

For Play 2.2 and over (perhaps some older versions as well),if you have used [the stage task](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Production), which means building your app with

> play clean stage

and running it with

> target/universal/stage/bin/foo

considering that your app is called foo. Then, your logs will be at

> target/universal/stage/logs/application.log

Comment: How about the startup logs of Play? As in my command just quits as soon I launch it in universal/stage. I need to know what's breaking it, but there is no log file under the stage ffolder! Any idea?